# AsyncTask not getting executed twice when creating a new instance

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having an requirement to execute `Asynctask` more than once. Hence I am creating a new instance of `Asynctask` everytime. The pseudo code is below

```
public void sendToServer(final String messagetoSend,Context context){

AsyncHttpPost wst = new AsyncHttpPost(messagetoSend);
wst.execute();
System.out.println("GET OUT");
System.out.println("SENDING TO SERVER");
}
```

I am calling the `sendToServer` function from `onResume` method. `Asynctask` is getting executed for the first time without fail. But for the second time, it is not getting executed. I am getting GETOUT and SENDING TO SERVER statements in logcat. But the task is not getting executed. Let me know where I am missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this:  wst.execute();
After api level greater 11:    wst.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null); Async task pool is one below 11 . so it is waiting to execute it.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. This is working. I am also targeting android version which is less than 11. What to do in this scenario?

Comment: Let it be , one thing make ur AsyncHtpppost is globel and cacel it if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling it once  here. To call it again, you will have to include another `wst.execute()` statement next to the previous one like below:-

```
public void sendToServer(final String messagetoSend,Context context){

    AsyncHttpPost wst = new AsyncHttpPost(messagetoSend);
    wst.execute();
    wst.execute();
    System.out.println("GET OUT");
    System.out.println("SENDING TO SERVER");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write new AsyncHttpPost(messagetoSend).execute() instead the 3 other rows. If you want to target different versions just make an if statement that checks the version of yhe device and use one or the other plementation depensing on that.